# Python easy way to set default encoding for opening files in text mode?

Tags: python, character-encoding

Is there an easy and cross-platform way to set default encoding for opening files (text mode) in Python, so you don't have to write

```
open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

each time and can simply write

```
open(filename, 'r')
```

?

Comment: define your own `open` function? e.g. `def myopen(*args): return open(*args,encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from io import open  # for python2 compatibility

old_open = open
def open(*args, **kwargs):
    encoding = kwargs.pop('encoding', 'utf8')
    return old_open(*args, encoding=encoding, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure there is a method named `open` you mentioned above, then define such a function

```
import functools    
open_file = functools.partial(open, encoding='utf-8')
```

then, open file with this new method,

```
f = open_file('some_file.txt', 'r')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own contextmanager:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def start_transaction(f ,mode="r", enc="utf-8"):
    f = open(f, mode, encoding=enc)
    try:
        yield f
    except:
        raise
with start_transaction("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print (line)
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this easy way, but it's an interesting approach, tnx

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for Python 3.7 and up: you can set PYTHONUTF8 environment variable to 1. Reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#utf8-mode

> The Python UTF-8 Mode ignores the locale encoding and forces the usage of the UTF-8 encoding

Some background knowledge for hungers:

- `open()` calls `locale.getpreferredencoding()` to get **default encoding** if you are not passing it explicitly https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open . Keyword here is **locale**.
- locale can not be easily retrieved and system dependant so Python does it best to guess it, and sometimes, it's not what you want. https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding

BTW, setting environment variable is useful when you don't have the control over the source code, OR the number of files need to be changed is huge.